# Debugging jquery mobile on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile

So I'm learning jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to run the following code below in my Android emulator.  What I was trying to do is to use $.mobile.changePage() method to navigate to my Contacts page (contact.html).  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, because I'm not even seeing the alert() call I placed into my JS.

I'm using jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css, jquery-1.6.4.min.js, and jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js in my html file.

I have an html5 button tag with an id of "html5Btn" in my code.  I have wrapped that button in a "div" with a data-role='content' attribute.

Can someone explain...

1. What I'm doing wrong in my code?
2. How do I debug JS in Eclipse?  I'm not seeing any errors in my LogCat?  Is this where I even look for jQuery errors?

   ```
   //CHANGE PAGE USING changePage()...placed this code 
   $("#html5Btn").bind('click', function(event) {
       alert("in JS");
       $.mobile.changePage('contact.html');
   }, false);
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
//CHANGE PAGE USING changePage()...placed this code 
$("#html5Btn").live('click', function(event) {
    alert("in JS");
    $.mobile.changePage('contact.html');
}, false);
```

For debugging, firebug is your friend! Also, I'm using intellij 11 ultimate... I must say the javascript debugger is nice!

Comment: So when you try to develop something for the Android platform using jQuery mobile, you debug in Firebug and code in Eclipse?

Comment: No, I edit in intellij and use it's javascript debugger for debugging locally in firefox and chrome. I do use firebug occasionally too... just depends on what I'm doing. For android I use the sdk's adb tool to look at the console. I just started looking into this for android debugging. http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

Comment: Thank you that worked, which leads me to ask why ".live()" worked and not ".bind()" or even ".click()"

Comment: My guess is that the #html5Btn isn't in the dom when the jquery/javascript code that does the binding is executed. Take a look at this http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/